# my ldap is already synchronised but i want to add 2 attributes

Tags: active-directory, ldap, alfresco, alfresco-share

First of all, I've add 2 things in the repo  `Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\subsystems\Authentication\ldap-ad\`

1. a copy of ldap-ad, I renamed it ldap-ad1
2. a copy of `common-ldap-context.xml`
   in the `Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\subsystems\Authentication\ldap-ad\common-ldap-context.xml`

I added 2 entries

```
    <property name="personAttributeMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="cm:userName">
                <!-- Must match the same attribute as userIdAttributeName -->
                <value>${ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName}</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="cm:firstName">
                <!-- OpenLDAP: "givenName" -->
                <!-- Active Directory: "givenName" -->
                <value>${ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName}</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="cm:lastName">
                <!-- OpenLDAP: "sn" -->
                <!-- Active Directory: "sn" -->
                <value>${ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName}</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="cm:email">
                <!-- OpenLDAP: "mail" -->
                <!-- Active Directory: "???" -->
                <value>${ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName}</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="cm:organization">
                <!-- OpenLDAP: "o" -->
                <!-- Active Directory: "???" -->
                <value>${ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName}</value>
            </entry>
            <!-- This deprecated property has been replaced by "cm:organization". We will use the same mapping -->
            <entry key="cm:organizationId">
                <!-- OpenLDAP: "o" -->
                <!-- Active Directory: "???" -->
                <value>${ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName}</value>
            </entry>
            <!-- Always use the default -->
            <entry key="cm:homeFolderProvider">
                <null/>
            </entry>
            <entry key="cm:jobtitle">
              <value>${ldap.synchronization.userJobTitleAttributeName}</value>
          </entry>
          <entry key="cm:location">
              <value>${ldap.synchronization.userLocationAttributeName}</value>
          </entry>
      </map>
    </property>
    <!-- Set a default home folder provider -->
    <!-- Defaults only apply for values above -->
    <property name="personAttributeDefaults">
        <map>
            <entry key="cm:homeFolderProvider">
                <value>${ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider}</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
```

I added into

```
/alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Authentication/ldap-ad/ldap-ad1/ldap-ad-authentication.properties
```

these 2 attributes

```
ldap.synchronization.userJobTitleAttributeName=title
ldap.synchronization.userLocationAttributeName=department
```

This is my `alfresco-global.properties` file:

```
    ###############################
    ## Common Alfresco Properties #
    ###############################

    dir.root=C:/Alfresco/alf_data

    alfresco.context=alfresco
    alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
    alfresco.port=8080
    alfresco.protocol=http

    share.context=share
    share.host=127.0.0.1
    share.port=8080
    share.protocol=http

    ### database connection properties ###
    db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
    db.username=alfresco
    db.password=admin
    db.name=alfresco
    db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}

    #--------------------------------------------->  debut modif 


    ### E-mail site invitation setting ###
    notification.email.siteinvite=true
    mail.host=test2015.test.be
    mail.port=25
    ###mail.encoding=UTF-8
    mail.from.default=alfresco@test.be
    mail.from.enabled=true
    ###mail.protocol=smtp
    mail.username=alfresco@test.be
    mail.password=testone
    ###activities.feed.notifier.enabled=false

    authentication.chain==ldap-ad1:ldap-ad,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm

    ### LDAP Integration ###
    synchronization.import.cron=0 0/30 9-18 ? * MON-FRI
    synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false
    synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=true
    synchronization.authCreatePeopleOnLogin=true
    ldap.synchronization.active=true
    ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://C2SRVDC1.test.be:389
    ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=alfresco@test.be
    ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=Henry
    ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou\=Institut erasme,dc\=erasme,dc=be
    ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=Institut erasme,dc=\erasme,dc=be


    ldap.authentication.active=true
    ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s@erasme.be
    ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple

    ################# ATTRIBUTE MAPPING #############
    #### mapping to unique username in username attribute### 
    #ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=cn
    #ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
    #ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
    ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
    #ldap.synchronization.groupType=
    #ldap.synchronization.personType=
    ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=member
    #ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=company

    ##-------------------------FIN DE LA MODIFICATION

    ### FTP Server Configuration ###
    ftp.enabled=true
    ftp.port=21

    ### RMI service ports ###
    alfresco.rmi.services.port=50500
    avm.rmi.service.port=0
    avmsync.rmi.service.port=0
    attribute.rmi.service.port=0
    authentication.rmi.service.port=0
    repo.rmi.service.port=0
    action.rmi.service.port=0
    deployment.rmi.service.port=0

    ### External executable locations ###
    ooo.exe=C:/Alfresco/libreoffice/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe
    ooo.enabled=true
    ooo.port=8100
    img.root=C:\\Alfresco\\imagemagick
    img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
    img.config=${img.root}\\config
    img.gslib=${img.root}\\lib
    img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe
    swf.exe=C:/Alfresco/swftools/pdf2swf.exe
    swf.languagedir=C:/Alfresco/swftools/japanese

    jodconverter.enabled=false
    jodconverter.officeHome=C:/Alfresco/libreoffice/App/libreoffice
    jodconverter.portNumbers=8100

    ### Initial admin password ###
    alfresco_user_store.adminpassword=209c6174da490caeb422f3fa5a7ae634

    ### E-mail site invitation setting ###
    notification.email.siteinvite=false

    ### License location ###
    dir.license.external=C:/Alfresco

    ### Solr indexing ###
    index.subsystem.name=solr
    dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
    solr.port.ssl=8443

    ### BPM Engine ###
    system.workflow.engine.jbpm.enabled=false
```

My logs are here

```
    13:20:17,142 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 03090004 IO exception parsing request
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 03090004 IO exception parsing request
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.solr.AlfrescoModelsDiff.executeImpl(AlfrescoModelsDiff.java:51)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.executeImpl(DeclarativeWebScript.java:235)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:64)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:422)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:268)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:532)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:563)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:346)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:167)
        at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:112)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.InputStreamContent.getContent(InputStreamContent.java:70)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.solr.AlfrescoModelsDiff.buildModel(AlfrescoModelsDiff.java:78)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.solr.AlfrescoModelsDiff.executeImpl(AlfrescoModelsDiff.java:42)
        ... 30 more
    13:20:17,144 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 03090005 IO exception parsing request
    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 03090005 IO exception parsing request
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.solr.AlfrescoModelsDiff.executeImpl(AlfrescoModelsDiff.java:51)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.executeImpl(DeclarativeWebScript.java:235)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:64)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:422)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:268)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:532)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:563)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:346)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:167)
        at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:112)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.InputStreamContent.getContent(InputStreamContent.java:70)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.solr.AlfrescoModelsDiff.buildModel(AlfrescoModelsDiff.java:78)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.solr.AlfrescoModelsDiff.executeImpl(AlfrescoModelsDiff.java:42)
        ... 30 more
```

i think that i forget nothing, 
thank you for all

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the AD attributes in alfresco-global.properties like:

```
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
ldap.synchronization.userCompanyTelephoneAttributeName=telephone
ladp.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
ldap.synchronisation.userIdAttributeName=uid
ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider=largeHomeFolderProvider
```